# Latent class analysis decreasing number of observations?

Tags: r

I'm trying to run a latent class analysis on a large public opinion survey, and I've run into an issue where the amount of observations at the close of the latent class are less than the number of observations in the initial data. This is inhibiting me in analysis, as I want to attach the class characterization variable to my original dataset and run some statistics/make graphs.

Below is a small snippet of the code, with ur being the dataset that I want to run the LCA on.
The problem is that when I create ur, I am given a dataset of 1948 obs, while after the latent class I am returned a set with 1943 obs.

> ur<-dat[complete.cases(dat[, 91:104])==T,]
>
> f<-cbind(Q42_1, Q42_3, Q42_4, Q42_5, Q42_6, Q42_7, Q42_8, Q42_9,
> Q43_1, Q43_2, Q43_3, Q43_4, Q43_5,
> Q43_6)~factor(pid3)+factor(inc)+factor(edu)+
> factor(own)+factor(age)+married+factor(Q59)+male+emp
>
> lca2<-poLCA(f, ur, nclass=2, maxiter=50000, tol=0.00000000000001,
> nrep=5)

Also, all of the listed questions included in the latent class are contained within the 91:104 range of dat that was specified.

How can I rectify this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default poLCA omits cases where any of the manifest variables are missing. It also omits cases where any of the covariates are missing. This is called 'casewise deletion' and it's the commonest way of dealing with missing values.
This seems the most likely explanation of losing cases as you go along.

The poLCA command options are :-

```
poLCA(formula, data, nclass = 2, maxiter = 1000, graphs = FALSE, 
      tol = 1e-10, na.rm = TRUE, probs.start = NULL, nrep = 1, 
      verbose = TRUE, calc.se = TRUE)
```

The help file says :-

- **na.rm**

*Logical, for how poLCA handles cases with missing values on the manifest variables. If TRUE, those cases are removed (listwise deleted) before estimating the model. If FALSE, cases with missing values are retained. Cases with missing covariates are always removed. The default is TRUE.*

and I think setting

```
na.rm = FALSE
```

will keep all the records with missing values for the manifest variables (but not the covariates) in.